# Mapear procedure no EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou usando o EntityFrameworkCore 3.0 juntamente com Stored Procedure. A procedure sp_login retorna os seguintes dados:

```
cod_us  A   B   C   D   E
111342  1   1   1   0   0
111342  1   2   1   1   1
111342  1   3   1   1   1
```

Modelos:

```
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    [Column("cod_us")]
    public int CodUs { get; private set; }

    [Column("A")]
    public int iA { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("B")]
    public ICollection<LoginPer> LoginPers { get; set; }
}

public class LoginPer
{
    [Key]
    [Column("B")]
    public int iB { get; private set; }

    [Column("C")]
    public bool bC { get; private set; }

    [Column("D")]
    public bool bD { get; private set; }

    [Column("E")]
    public bool bE { get; private set; }
}
```

Quero mapear para uma estrutura parecida com essa:

```
{
    "cod_us": 111342,
    "A": 1,
    "LoginPers": [
        {"B": 1, "C": 1, "D": 0, "E": 0},
        {"B": 2, "C": 1, "D": 1, "E": 1},
        {"B": 3, "C": 1, "D": 1, "E": 1}
    ]
}
```

Como faria isso?

Comment: Porque precisa mapear isso? Não é só resultado que precisa?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o linq para alterar os dados depois de realizar a sua query.

Pode agrupar por cod_us com o `GroupBy`

```cs
var respostaAgrupada = respostaProcedure.GroupBy(x => x.cod_us);
```

E posteriormente usar o `.Select` para criar o seu novo objeto.

```cs
var respostaMapeada = respostaProcedure
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.CodUs, x.iA })
    .Select(x => new Login
    {
        CodUs = x.Key.CodUs,
        iA = x.Key.iA,
        LoginPers = x.Select(l => new LoginPer { bC = l.bC, bD = l.bD, bE = l.bE, iB = l.iB }).ToList()
    });
```

Exemplo completo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OTr2i1